# How do I adjust the separation between left and right eye in a 3D anaglyph video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, 3d, color-depth

How do I adjust the separation between the left (green) and right (magenta) channels when converting 3D sbs to 3D anaglyph (green/magenta) video using ffmpeg? I've search "the net" but can't find any means to get the ffmpeg "stereo3d" (or some other) filter to perform this function.

In sample 3D sbs videos converted to 3D green/magenta (using ffmpeg stereo3d "agmd" filter), the green/magenta separation of "close" objects is too great and cannot be focused on as one image when using the green/magenta glasses. Images further away in the scene have a lesser separation and look fine.

Example: `ffmpeg -i test_3dsbsl.mp4 -vf "stereo3d=sbsl:agmd" test_3dagmd.mp4`

Any one?

Comment: I may be misinterpreting this, but isn't that basically "baked in" in the original side-by-side 3D video? I don't see how it could be changed without filming the scene again with a different lens distance.

Comment: Daniel B: The 3D sbs is two separate images "stacked" horizontally, side-by-side. The 3D simulation using the anaglyph method results in a single D image. The left sbs image is color-shifted to a more green image and the right sbs image is color-shifted to a more magenta image. These green (left) and red (right) images are overlayed into a single 2D image to be viewed with a pair of green/magenta "3D glasses. So what i'm looking to do is adjust the "shift" of the green and the red because in close up objects, the grn/mag shift is too great and one can't focus on those up-close objects.